# How to do RPC over socket.io?

Tags: callback, socket.io, rpc, socket.io-1.0

Suppose we have a simple echo server (*tuned to be longer on the first request*):

```js
var waiting = 8000;
io.on('connection', function(socket){   
    socket.on('doEcho', function (data) {
        setTimeout( function () {
            socket.emit('echoDone', data);
        }, waiting);
        waiting = 1;
    });
});
```

Then say a `index.html` client script does:

```js
askEcho ("11111", function (resp) {
         console.log("answer for 11111 " + resp);
});
askEcho ("22222", function (resp) {
         console.log("answer for 22222 " + resp);
});
```

where `askEcho` is the following buggy function, pretending to be an RPC stub:

```js
function askEcho (text, fun) {
     socket.emit('doEcho', text);
     socket.on('echoDone', function (data) {
         fun ( data );
     });
  }
```

And obviously what I get is the following mess

```
answer for 11111  22222
answer for 22222  22222
answer for 11111  11111
answer for 22222  11111
```

because I installed two listeners for the same event. This can be worked around easily,
but I don't see that clear how to get the responses properly ordered at the client, 
without help (programming more) at the server side.

This all seems a bit too much burden.
Can't be the `askEcho` function coded right and easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a simple trick: use a counter to differentiate between the answers, and remove the callback when done (*even better use `once` instead of `on`*). This only poses minor changes at server and client sides.

Let's show it:

The echo server is (*now without any delaying timeout*):

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){   
    socket.on('doEcho', function (callCounter, data) {    
        socket.emit('echoDone'+callCounter, data);
    });
});
```

In the client side (*`index.html`*) the user code is still the same, as desired:

```js
askEcho ("11111", function (resp) {
    console.log("answer for 11111 " + resp);
});
askEcho ("22222", function (resp) {
    console.log("answer for 22222 " + resp);
});
```

and this is the stub `askEcho` that works properly in teamwork with the server side:

```js
var callCounter = 0;
function askEcho (text, fun) {
     var localCallCounter = ++callCounter;
     socket.emit('doEcho', localCallCounter, text);
     socket.once('echoDone'+localCallCounter, function (data) {
         // not required: socket.removeListener ('echoDone'+localCallCounter);
         fun ( data );
     });
 }
```

Comment: and if you're too lazy to implement it yourself, I have this small library: https://github.com/capaj/socket.io-rpc

Comment: There are situations when callback is never removed. It's a pain to handle them (timeouts, cleanup on disconnect etc), so I wouldn't call this a simple trick.

Answer (score 5):

With socket.io you can send and receive acknowledgements via callbacks.

See this: http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)